# Removing lagging latency in drawing UIBezierPath smooth lines in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, uibezierpath

The code below draws smooth curved lines by overriding touches, but there is noticeable lagging or latency. The code uses `addCurveToPoint` and calls `setNeedsDisplay` after every 4 touch points which causes a jumpy appearance as the drawing doesn't keep up with finger movements. To remove the lagging or perceived latency, touch points 1, 2, 3 (leading up to touch point 4) could be temporarily filled with `addQuadCurveToPoint` and `addLineToPoint`.

1. How can this actually be achieved in code to remove perceived lagging by using a temporary Line and QuadCurved line before displaying a final Curved line?
2. If the below class is attached to one `UIView` (e.g. viewOne or `self`), how do I make a copy of the drawing to another `UIView` outside the class (e.g. viewTwo) after `touchesEnded`?

   ```
    //  ViewController.swift

   import UIKit

   class drawSmoothCurvedLinesWithLagging: UIView {

       let path=UIBezierPath()
       var incrementalImage:UIImage?

       var points = [CGPoint?](count: 5, repeatedValue: nil)

       var counter:Int?

       var strokeColor:UIColor?

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       }

       override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
           autoreleasepool {
               incrementalImage?.drawInRect(rect)
               strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
               strokeColor?.setStroke()
               path.lineWidth = 20
               path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round
               path.stroke()
           }
       }

       override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
           counter = 0

           let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
           points[0] = touch!.locationInView(self)
       }

       override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
           let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
           let point = touch!.locationInView(self)

           counter = counter! + 1
           points[counter!] = point


           if counter == 2{
               //use path.addLineToPoint ?
               //use self.setNeedsDisplay() ?
           }

           if counter == 3{
               //use path.addQuadCurveToPoint ?
               //use self.setNeedsDisplay() ?
           }

           if counter == 4{
               points[3]! = CGPointMake((points[2]!.x + points[4]!.x)/2.0, (points[2]!.y + points[4]!.y)/2.0)
               path.moveToPoint(points[0]!)
               path.addCurveToPoint(points[3]!, controlPoint1: points[1]!, controlPoint2: points[2]!)

               self.setNeedsDisplay()

               points[0]! = points[3]!
               points[1]! = points[4]!
               counter = 1
           }
       }

       override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
           self.drawBitmap()
           self.setNeedsDisplay()
           path.removeAllPoints()
           counter = 0
       }

       override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
           self.touchesEnded(touches!, withEvent: event)
       }

       func drawBitmap(){
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
           strokeColor?.setStroke()
           if((incrementalImage) == nil){
               let rectPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
               UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
               rectPath.fill()
           }

           incrementalImage?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
           path.stroke()
           incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       }

   }

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       }

       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
           super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
           // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }


   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, adding a curve every few points will give it a stuttering lag. So, yes, you can reduce this affect by adding a line to `points[1]`, adding a quad curve to `points[2]` and adding a cubic curve to `points[3]`.

   As you said, make sure to add this to a separate path, though. So, in Swift 3/4:

   ```
   class SmoothCurvedLinesView: UIView {
       var strokeColor = UIColor.blue
       var lineWidth: CGFloat = 20
       var snapshotImage: UIImage?

       private var path: UIBezierPath?
       private var temporaryPath: UIBezierPath?
       private var points = [CGPoint]()

       override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
           snapshotImage?.draw(in: rect)

           strokeColor.setStroke()

           path?.stroke()
           temporaryPath?.stroke()
       }

       override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
           if let touch = touches.first {
               points = [touch.location(in: self)]
           }
       }

       override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
           guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
           let point = touch.location(in: self)

           points.append(point)

           updatePaths()

           setNeedsDisplay()
       }

       private func updatePaths() {
           // update main path

           while points.count > 4 {
               points[3] = CGPoint(x: (points[2].x + points[4].x)/2.0, y: (points[2].y + points[4].y)/2.0)

               if path == nil {
                   path = createPathStarting(at: points[0])
               }

               path?.addCurve(to: points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])

               points.removeFirst(3)

               temporaryPath = nil
           }

           // build temporary path up to last touch point

           if points.count == 2 {
               temporaryPath = createPathStarting(at: points[0])
               temporaryPath?.addLine(to: points[1])
           } else if points.count == 3 {
               temporaryPath = createPathStarting(at: points[0])
               temporaryPath?.addQuadCurve(to: points[2], controlPoint: points[1])
           } else if points.count == 4 {
               temporaryPath = createPathStarting(at: points[0])
               temporaryPath?.addCurve(to: points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])
           }
       }

       override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
           finishPath()
       }

       override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
           finishPath()
       }

       private func finishPath() {
           constructIncrementalImage()
           path = nil
           setNeedsDisplay()
       }

       private func createPathStarting(at point: CGPoint) -> UIBezierPath {
           let localPath = UIBezierPath()

           localPath.move(to: point)

           localPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
           localPath.lineCapStyle = .round
           localPath.lineJoinStyle = .round

           return localPath
       }

       private func constructIncrementalImage() {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
           strokeColor.setStroke()
           snapshotImage?.draw(at: .zero)
           path?.stroke()
           temporaryPath?.stroke()
           snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       }
   }
   ```

   You could even marry this with iOS 9 predictive touches (as I described [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579957/drawing-class-drawing-straight-lines-instead-of-curved-lines/34583708)), which could reduce lag even further.
2. To take this resulting image and use it elsewhere, you can just grab the `incrementalImage` (which I renamed to `snapshotImage`, above), and drop it into an image view of the other view.

For Swift 2 rendition, see previous [revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34997902/10).

Comment: thank you very much. Brilliant! Appreciate your clear explanations. I will try grabbing the `snapshotImage`. I have noticed though two artefacts in the code.
1 - When drawing, lifting the finger, then beginning drawing again, it appears the last part of the previous drawing is removed and replaced with a thin line. This only occurs sometimes. Image: http://i.imgur.com/LIpfF4q.png
2 - A flat squared off corner appears when drawing. This also only occurs sometimes. Image: http://i.imgur.com/QyWpXG0.png
What is causing these artefacts?

Comment: Good catch. Yes, the issue is that you were configuring the attributes only when `drawRect` was called, but `constructIncrementalImage` doesn't. But, the configuring of the `UIBezierPath` really doesn't belong in `drawRect` at all. It really should be set when the path is instantiated. So, I wrote a method to instantiate and configure a path, and use that whenever I need to create a path. See revised answer above.

Comment: I have noticed one other issue regarding accumulated lagging latency during continuous drawing that your insights might be able to help solve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067811

Comment: Would it be possible for you to briefly explain what is occurring in the section of code above when `pointCount == 5` and how it compares with `pointCount == 3`, both of which use `addCurveToPoint` quad bezier curves?

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of simplified code but I’ve noticed since the change, sometimes a double line is present at the end of drawing, image: http://i.imgur.com/vU96UT5.png To try track down the issue, I’ve set lineWidth: CGFloat = 1 and added print(points.count) to the beginning of touchesEnded. Turns out when touching up when points.count = 2 the double line presents but I can’t work out why that is comparing the previous code. (It doesn’t happen on 3 and 4.) Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: Sorry, @Rob. Let me correct myself. Yes, I'm using the exact same code above. All I have changed is `lineWidth: CGFloat = 1` and I have added `print(points.count)` just under `private func updatePaths() {`. When I run this, do lots of short drawings, it shows that when `points.count = 5`, a double line is produced. http://pastie.org/private/bjifufdrnpljt9xscfcogg

Comment: @user4806509 - We can simplify further (getting rid of `pointsCount`) and the issue is remedied. See revised answer

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help and patience @Rob. (I posted a different type of question yesterday about scale affine transformations if you are interested in looking at that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207177/scale-affine-transformation-scaling-differently-on-ios7-and-ios8-ios9-in-swift )
Thanks again. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Rob Thanks again. I have a new problem based on this code regarding adding an eraser function. If you are interested in looking at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511211