# Removing lagging latency during continuous period of drawing UIBezierPath in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, uibezierpath

The code below draws lines by overriding touches, however lagging begins to occur over a period of continuous non stop drawing. This lagging accumulates and gets worse the longer the finger remains moving across the screen. The result is the CPU nearly maxes out on an actual device (CPU 98%+) and the resulting image looks choppy the longer the drawing continues.

Also, when drawing extra fast especially in circles, there is a discrepancy in the paths drawn between the `path` and `temporaryPath` (or `localPath`). Although they are being drawn at different times, they seem to appear on screen simultaneously which is visually distracting seeing two paths drawing fast. The inner path (`path`) appears to be a distance away from the outer path (`temporaryPath`) highlighted in red in one of the below images.

1 - How can the lagging latency over a period of continuous drawing be eliminated?

2 - How can the discrepancy in the paths drawn be eliminated?

3 - How can the alpha/opacity of the `path` and `temporaryPath` be changed?

[image]

```
class swiftView: UIView {

var strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5
var snapshotImage: UIImage?

private var path: UIBezierPath?
private var temporaryPath: UIBezierPath?
private var points = [CGPoint]()

var counterPoints:Int?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    autoreleasepool {

    snapshotImage?.drawInRect(rect)

    strokeColor.setStroke()

    path?.stroke()
    temporaryPath?.stroke()

    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
    points = [touch!.locationInView(self)]

    counterPoints = 0
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
    let point = touch!.locationInView(self)

    points.append(point)
    let pointCount = points.count

    counterPoints = counterPoints! + 1

    if pointCount == 2 {
        temporaryPath = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
        temporaryPath?.addLineToPoint(points[1])
        setNeedsDisplay()
    } else if pointCount == 3 {
        temporaryPath = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
        temporaryPath?.addQuadCurveToPoint(points[2], controlPoint: points[1])
        setNeedsDisplay()
    } else if pointCount == 4 {
        temporaryPath = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
        temporaryPath?.addCurveToPoint(points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])
//            setNeedsDisplay()

        if counterPoints! < 50 {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        } else {
            temporaryPath = nil
            self.constructIncrementalImage()
            path = nil
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            counterPoints = 0
        }

    } else if pointCount == 5 {
        points[3] = CGPointMake((points[2].x + points[4].x)/2.0, (points[2].y + points[4].y)/2.0)

        // create a quad bezier up to point 4, too

        if points[4] != points[3] {
            let length = hypot(points[4].x - points[3].x, points[4].y - points[3].y) / 2.0
            let angle = atan2(points[3].y - points[2].y, points[4].x - points[3].x)
            let controlPoint = CGPoint(x: points[3].x + cos(angle) * length, y: points[3].y + sin(angle) * length)

            temporaryPath = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[3])
            temporaryPath?.addQuadCurveToPoint(points[4], controlPoint: controlPoint)
        } else {
            temporaryPath = nil
        }

        if path == nil {
            path = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
        }

        path?.addCurveToPoint(points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])

        self.setNeedsDisplay()

        points = [points[3], points[4]]
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.constructIncrementalImage()
    path = nil
    self.setNeedsDisplay()

    counterPoints = 0
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesEnded(touches!, withEvent: event)
}

private func createPathStartingAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UIBezierPath {
    let localPath = UIBezierPath()

    localPath.moveToPoint(point)

    localPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    localPath.lineCapStyle = .Round
    localPath.lineJoinStyle = .Round

    return localPath
}

private func constructIncrementalImage() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    strokeColor.setStroke()
    snapshotImage?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
    path?.stroke()
    temporaryPath?.stroke()
    snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

}
```

Comment: You say "I’ve tried caching the drawing when pointCount == 4 after about 50 continuous drawing points". Well, perhaps you should show us that code, because that's precisely how one might solve this problem. But perhaps 50 is too few (because when you're talking about gestures, the touches rack up quickly, especially if using coalesced touches). But taking a snapshot is the typical solution (realizing that the snapshot process itself is slow, so you'll want to balance the frequency of snapshots with the length of the path).

Comment: @Rob Yes, some updated code would have be helpful. I’ve updated it, sorry about that. I’ve also updated the question/s. To the code, a variable `counterPoints` has been added. I’ve also added `autoreleasepool` to `drawRect` to help avoid the class from crashing. Not certain that is helpful or unnecessary, but I’ve noticed it can help sometime avoid CPU crashes in the past. Coalesced touches haven’t been used as I’m experimenting on iOS7 as well as iOS9. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> 1. How can the lagging latency over a period of continuous drawing be eliminated?

As you correctly surmised, yes, doing a snapshot and resetting the path can fix this by limiting how long the path will be.

I know you're aware of this, but for the benefit of other readers, in iOS 9 you can use predictive touches, too. In this particular algorithm (where (a) you're simply adding to a path, but (b) every fourth point is adjusted on the basis of the next point to ensure that there are no discontinuities where the two cubic bezier curves join) that's a little tricky, but could be done.

> 2. How can the discrepancy in the paths drawn be eliminated?

This is caused because the snapshot is including the temporary path. But the whole purpose of that temporary path is that it will be discarded as more points come in. So you shouldn't include it in the snapshot you create mid-gesture.

So, I'd suggest adding a parameter to the snapshot function which indicates whether the `temporaryPath` should be included or not. When calling it mid-gesture, you'd specify `includeTemporaryPath` as `false`, but when calling it at the end of the gesture, `includeTemporaryPath` would be `true`.

For example:

```
class SmoothCurvedLinesView: UIView {
    var strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 20
    var snapshotImage: UIImage?

    private var path: UIBezierPath?
    private var temporaryPath: UIBezierPath?
    private var points = [CGPoint]()
    private var totalPointCount = 0

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        snapshotImage?.drawInRect(rect)

        strokeColor.setStroke()

        path?.stroke()
        temporaryPath?.stroke()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
        points = [touch!.locationInView(self)]
        totalPointCount = totalPointCount + 1
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
        let point = touch!.locationInView(self)

        points.append(point)
        totalPointCount = totalPointCount + 1

        updatePaths()

        if totalPointCount > 50 {
            constructIncrementalImage(includeTemporaryPath: false)
            path = nil
            totalPointCount = 0
        }

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    private func updatePaths() {
        // update main path

        while points.count > 4 {
            points[3] = CGPointMake((points[2].x + points[4].x)/2.0, (points[2].y + points[4].y)/2.0)

            if path == nil {
                path = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
            }

            path?.addCurveToPoint(points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])

            points.removeFirst(3)
        }

        // build temporary path up to last touch point

        let pointCount = points.count

        if pointCount == 2 {
            temporaryPath = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
            temporaryPath?.addLineToPoint(points[1])
        } else if pointCount == 3 {
            temporaryPath = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
            temporaryPath?.addQuadCurveToPoint(points[2], controlPoint: points[1])
        } else if pointCount == 4 {
            temporaryPath = createPathStartingAtPoint(points[0])
            temporaryPath?.addCurveToPoint(points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        constructIncrementalImage()
        path = nil
        temporaryPath = nil
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        touchesEnded(touches!, withEvent: event)
    }

    private func createPathStartingAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UIBezierPath {
        let localPath = UIBezierPath()

        localPath.moveToPoint(point)

        localPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
        localPath.lineCapStyle = .Round
        localPath.lineJoinStyle = .Round

        return localPath
    }

    private func constructIncrementalImage(includeTemporaryPath includeTemporaryPath: Bool = true) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        strokeColor.setStroke()
        snapshotImage?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
        path?.stroke()
        if (includeTemporaryPath) { temporaryPath?.stroke() }
        snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

By the way, while I was the one who provided that path generation code, I realized it could be streamlined a bit. I also fixed a bug, too. See above code.

You then asked:

> 3. How can the alpha/opacity of the path and temporaryPath be changed?

You can just adjust the color with which you call `setStroke` with the appropriate alpha. For example, if you wanted the temporary path to be at half of the `alpha` of the main path, you could do something like:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    snapshotImage?.drawInRect(rect)

    strokeColor.setStroke()
    path?.stroke()

    strokeColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).setStroke()
    temporaryPath?.stroke()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of simplified code- compact! But I’ve noticed since the change, sometimes a double line is present at the end of drawing, image: http://i.imgur.com/vU96UT5.png
To try track down the issue, I’ve set `lineWidth: CGFloat = 1` and added `print(points.count)` to the beginning of `touchesEnded`. Turns out when touching up when `points.count = 2` the double line presents but I can’t work out why that is comparing the previous code. (It doesn’t happen on `3` and `4`.) Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: I've noticed an artefact in the above code. The details of which I've posted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608766